# Use any() to check if certain key exists in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I want to use jq to check if a keyword exists as a key in a JSON at any level. Here is what I came up with:

```
jq -c 'paths | select(.[-1]) as $p| index("headline") //empty' news.json
```

The output is an array:

```
[
  6,
  7,
  9
]
```

I want to map the output array to jq function `any()` and get an overall result as true if key exists or false if it doesn't.

How can I get that done with jq ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide `any` with an iterator and a condition

```sh
jq 'any(paths; .[-1] == "headline")'
```

You can also provide the `-e` (or `--exit-status`) option to have an exit status of `0` if the result was `true`, and `1` if the result was `false`, which can immediately be used for further processing in the shell.

```sh
jq -e 'any(paths; .[-1] == "headline")'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an intermediate array for that.

```
any(paths[-1]; . == "headline")
```